# Oracle: Unique constraint violated exception but my data does not actually violate it

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, execute, unique-constraint

I am trying to insert some data from excel file into a table. I have two excel file as follows:

```
Test2:
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ANC 1   52
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ANC 2   30
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ANC 3   34
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ANC 4   41
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ANC 5   53--->duplicate row
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ANC 6   18
5/12/2012      5/18/2012    ABQ ANC 7   4
5/12/2012      5/18/2012    ABQ ATL 1   389
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ATL 2   312
```

test1:

```
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ATL 4   259
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ATL 5   362
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ATL 6   240
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ATL 7   88
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ ANC 5   53--->duplicate row
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ AUS 2   2
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ BDL 1   164
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ BDL 2   128
5/12/2012     5/18/2012 ABQ BDL 3   132
```

My table, to start with is, empty. So I insert the first file(test2), it works fine. When inserting 2nd file(test1), it should give "Unique constraint violated" exception at row 5 of test1. I duplicated that row on purpose for testing. I wrote the following code to do the inserts. As you can see the batch size is 3.

When inserting second file, The code executes the first batch(which is the first 3 rows) fine. In the second batch(row 4-6), because one of the row(5) is duplicated, it throws BatchUpdatException. I catch that exception and in the catch block, I process each row(row 4-6) one at a time. So the insert for row 4 should have worked fine. But it doesn't. It instead throws an sqlException. Row 5 throws exception as well(duplicate row). But row 6 doesn't. Row 6 executeUpdate() runs fine. At this point if I look at my database table, I see that row 4 is also inserted into the table along with the row 6. How can this happen, it just threw ane exception at row 4?

My objective is to let the user know where the duplicate rows are. Because of this aberrant behavior, the user is told that there is a duplicate row in row 4 and row 5 when they try to insert the second file.

```
String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO DMD_VOL_UPLOAD (ORIGIN, DESTINATION, DAY_OF_WEEK, EFFECTIVE_DATE, DISCONTINUE_DATE, VOLUME)";
    int batchSize=3;
    sqlStatement += " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    con = session.connection();
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
    for(currentRow=1; currentRow<=rowCount; currentRow++){
        try{
                forecastBatch = (ForecastBatch) list.get(currentRow-1);                                 
                pstmt = (PreparedStatement) prepareStatement(pstmt, forecastBatch);         
                pstmt.addBatch();               
                if(currentRow % batchSize == 0 || currentRow==rowCount){
                    updateCounts = pstmt.executeBatch();
                    con.commit();
                    pstmt.clearBatch();
                }                           
        }catch(BatchUpdateException e){
                int endPoint = currentRow;
                int i;
                for(i=currentRow-batchSize; i<endPoint; i++){
                    forecastBatch = (ForecastBatch) list.get(i);
                    try{
                        pstmt = (PreparedStatement) prepareStatement(pstmt, forecastBatch); 
                        pstmt.executeUpdate();**strong text**
                        con.commit();
                    }catch(SQLException ex){
                        errorRowNum = errorRowNum + (i+1) + ", ";
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                }
        }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end of the first for loop
```

Comment: Have you tried doing an explicit rollback after the batch insert fails before trying to insert the rows individually?

Comment: No I haven't I'll try that out

Comment: @ Eric Petroelje That was it.I had to do explicit roll back. Thank you very much. Amaazzing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `executeBatch` a batch of statements, some of the statements may succeed and some of the statements may fail.  If one statement fails, that does not mean that the JDBC driver rolls back the statements that succeeded.  The JDBC driver may choose to attempt to execute all the statements in the batch if one statement fails or it may choose to stop executing statements in the batch once a statement fails (it sounds like the driver you're using chooses to stop executing statements as soon as there is a failure).

When you get a `BatchUpdateException`, you need to call `getUpdateCounts`.  That will give you an array of `int` that tells you either how many rows the statement updated, a `Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO` indicating the statement succeeded but no row count was available, or a `Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED` indicating that the statement failed.  I would expect that you would get back a two element array indicating that the first statement in the batch (row 4 in the spreadsheet) succeeded and that the second statement in the batch (row 5 in the spreadsheet) failed.  The lack of a third element in the array would indicate that the third statement in the batch (row 6 in the spreadsheet) was not executed.  Your retry code would need to retry only the statements that were not executed.  In this case, only the third statement (row 6 in the spreadsheet) would need to be retried because the `BatchUpdateException` already tells you that the first statement succeeded and the second statement failed.

Comment: Yes my driver stops executing when it encounters a failure. If my batch size is 3, and the 2nd statement in the batch fails, this leads to the failure of the previous statement as well. As a result I get an array of 3 elements when I call getUpdatecounts().The value of all the 3 elements are EXECUTE_FAILED. Now the problem is, finding out which statement in the batch threw the exception. As a result, I do not know where to start the retry from.

Comment: @javaStudent - That doesn't make sense.  If you get an array of 3 elements, that implies that the driver attempted to execute all three statements in the batch.  If all three elements of the array are `Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED`, that implies that all three statements failed.  That's not consistent with the rest of the behavior you're describing.  What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle 11g. I am not sure what driver that would be. I apologize, I am relatively new at this. What I did was as soon as I got the batchUpdateException, I looked at the values of the updatecounts and they were all EXECUTE_FAILED. Hence in my catch block, I try to process all the 3 statements one at a time.  Is there a way I can find out what jdbc driver I am using.

Comment: I had to add an explicit rollback statement before I started processng each row. I would like to thank you for taking the time to respond. People, such as yourself, make stackoverflow such a wonderful place to be.